# preg_replace with file_get_contents

Tags: php, function, preg-replace, file-get-contents

I have looked at a couple of questions here, and done a Google search but I cannot seem to find the correct way to go about doing this.

I am using this function

```
function replace_c($content){
    global $db;
    $replacements = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `replacements`");
    while($replace = $replacements->fetch_assoc()){
        preg_replace("/".$replace['triggers']."/i",$replace['php'], $content);
    }
    return $content;
}
```

and this is my call to the function

```
$contents = replace_c(file_get_contents("templates/" . $settings['theme'] . "/header.html"));
```

It doesn't give an error, it just doesn't replace the text like it should so I am not sure if the function is actually working. I did try `preg_replace_callback` but I don't think I fully understand how it works and was producing nothing but errors, do I have to go the callback route, or am I just missing something in my current function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kira,

The preg_Replace function returns the replaced string. The $content subject you post to it will not update as a reference. So try changing the code to;

```
$content = preg_replace("/".$replace['triggers']."/i",$replace['php'], $content);
```

Comment: Haha, people are fast. Thiefmaster has the same answer

Comment: Woooowww I feel like a moron for over looking that, works great now, sorry for such a dumb question guys!

Comment: No questions are stupid. Some are more easy to answer then others. Great to hear you got it working now!

Answer (score 2):

You never assign the return value of `preg_replace` to `$content`.... What you need is this:

```
$content = preg_replace("/".$replace['triggers']."/i",$replace['php'], $content);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the replaced content back to a variable.

```
$content = preg_replace(...);
```

Also, are you sure that an `str_replace()` wouldn't be enough?